# Can xvdc block devices on a Windows AMI be ignored?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ami

After performing the steps in [Is it possible to create an EBS AMI for windows EC2 instance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/355742/is-it-possible-to-create-an-ebs-ami-for-windows-ec2-instance) to create a Windows AMI from an "other linux" snapshot, I created an image of the fixed instance and the image does have platform set to Windows, but the block devices seem strange. In addition to the typical "/dev/sda1=snap-xxxx", it also lists 26 xvdc devices for some reason.

Would this cause any problems or can this be safely ignored?

The instance so far has been working just fine and successfully interacts with the rest of the CloudFormation instances as designed.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to create a *Windows* instance from a *Linux* AMI??

It’s such a non-standard approach that I guess the only success criteria is if it seems to work or not. And since it does work I guess it’s all good. :)

Regarding the extra disk devices - if you don’t use them you should be able to detach the volumes in the EC2 console.

—-

**Much better way** to create a new AMI is using one of the methods described on **[AWS VM Import/Export](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/)** page. That way you can create a clean, predictable AMI. Give it a try.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I actually started with a windows AMI, but after taking a snapshot of it, which is apparently not supported as described in the linked post, and using an image created from that snapshot, the platform changed to "other linux", even though the image still works like windows. I don't believe that the disk devices were actually created as volumes, they are just listed in the AMI description.